# Cannot drop AttributeAdapter tables -- "Declaration context is not set"

Tags: python, datajoint

I have created a dj.AttributeAdapter subclass for a custom datatype (attribute_type = filepath@external). However it does not seem to be working right -- when I attempt to drop the table for instance I get the very cryptic `AssertionError: Declaration context is not set`. But I declared the context in the schema as `schema = dj.schema('myschema', context=locals())`. What does this mean? Also, when I use `delete` it deletes the entry but not the file itself, how do I configure AttributeAdapter to pass this down?

Comment: Looking at the source code for this assertion error, your context is registering as `None`. It also looks like datajoint is trying to initialize from an existing database table. 

https://github.com/datajoint/datajoint-python/blob/master/datajoint/heading.py#L318

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the context is registering as `None`, initializing from an existing table.

Unfortunately, the DataJoint [`AttributeAdapter` class](https://github.com/datajoint/datajoint-python/blob/master/datajoint/attribute_adapter.py) does not yet support `delete` calls. One could request this feature by [submitting an issue](https://github.com/datajoint/datajoint-python/issues/new?assignees=&labels=enhancement%2C+awaiting-triage&template=feature_request.md&title=). As it stands, I would suggest using the `put` method to overwrite existing files and/or implementing an Imported table that checked all files against existing keys and removed additional files.